# How can I make this simple python movie recommendation program more efficent?

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm making a movie recommendation program and I have figured this way out but it seems very inefficient since it has a lot of repeating code for each genre.

Below is what I have so far, I haven't done all the genre's because i would just copy and paste what i have and change the genre. It seems like there is a much better way to go about it. Ive learned about different search algorithms but i don't know and understand how I would implement it in this situation.

```
movies = [
  ["Wedding Crashers", "Comedy", 2],
  ["Horrible Bosses", "Comedy", 1.75],
  ["Dodgeball", "Comedy", 1.5],
  ["Superbad", "Comedy", 2],
  ["Dumb and Dumber", "Comedy", 1.75],
  ["Shawshank Redemption", "Drama", 2.33],
  ["Goodwill Hunting", "Drama", 2],
  ["The Departed", "Drama", 2.5],
  ["Whiplash", "Drama", 1.75],
  ["Manchester by the Sea", "Drama", 2.25],
  ["Die Hard", "Action", 2.25],
  ["John Wick", "Action", 1.75],
  ["Terminator", "Action", 1.75],
  ["First Blood", "Action", 1.5],
  ["Predator", "Action", 1.75],
  ["The Conjuring", "Horror", 2],
  ["Sinister", "Horror", 2],
  ["Insidious", "Horror", 2]
]

def program():
  print("Welcome to our movie recommondation program!")
  print("We will help find a movie to watch!")
  start = input("Would you like to start? y/n ")
  if start == "y":
    genre = input("What genre are you interested in? - Comedy, Drama, Action, Horror - Please select one: ")

#COMEDY
    if genre == "comedy":
      length = input("Do you have a preference on the length of the movie? - 1.5 - 2, 2 - 2.5, 2.5+, No preference - Please select one: ")
      if length == "1.5 - 2":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Comedy" and movie[2] <= 2:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "2 - 2.5":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Comedy" and 2 < movie[2] <= 2.5:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "2.5+":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Comedy" and movie[2] > 2.5:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "No preference":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Comedy":
            print(movie)

#DRAMA
    if genre == "drama":
      length = input("Do you have a preference on the length of the movie? - 1.5 - 2, 2 - 2.5, 2.5+, No preference - Please select one: ")
      if length == "1.5 - 2":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Drama" and movie[2] <= 2:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "2 - 2.5":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Drama" and 2 < movie[2] <= 2.5:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "2.5+":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Drama" and movie[2] > 2.5:
            print(movie)
      elif length == "No preference":
        print("MOVIES WE RECOMMEND:")
        for movie in movies:
          if movie[1] == "Drama":
            print(movie)
    


program()
```

Comment: this is vauge thing, go through this https://medium.com/double-pointer/system-design-interview-recommendation-system-design-as-used-by-youtube-netflix-etc-c457aaec3ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this is helpful:

```
movies = [
    {
        "title": "Wedding Crashers",
        "genre": "Comedy",
        "duration": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Dodgeball",
        "genre": "Comedy",
        "duration": 1.5
    },
    {
        "title": "Goodwill Hunting",
        "genre": "Drama",
        "duration": 2
    },
    {
        "title": "Terminator",
        "genre": "Action",
        "duration": 1.75
    },
]

def get_genres(movies):
    return sorted(list(set(movie["genre"] for movie in movies)))

def main():
    genres = get_genres(movies)
    genres_pretty = ", ".join(genres)
    
    print(f"These are the genres: {genres_pretty}")

    # First, get the desired genre.
    prompt = "What genre are you interested in?: "
    while True:
        user_genre = input(prompt)
        if user_genre in genres:
            break
        prompt = "Not a valid genre, try again: "

    # Then, get the desired duration.
    prompt = "What's the maximum duration?: "
    while True:
        try:
            user_duration = int(input(prompt))
            break
        except:
            prompt = "Not a valid duration, try again: "

    # Then, filter all movies based on both criteria.
    recommended_movies = [movie for movie in movies if movie["genre"] == user_genre and movie["duration"] <= user_duration]
    recommended_movie_titles = [movie["title"] for movie in recommended_movies]
    recommended_movie_titles_pretty = ", ".join(recommended_movie_titles)
    print(f"We recommend: {recommended_movie_titles_pretty}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
These are the genres: Action, Comedy, Drama
What genre are you interested in?: Comedy
What's the maximum duration?: 2
We recommend: Wedding Crashers, Dodgeball
>>>
```